# Join on multiprocessing pool deadlock due to [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here's a contrived piece of code that runs exactly as expected:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from os import cpu_count

PROCESSES = cpu_count() // 2

N = 250

def add_to_list(the_list, the_value):
    try:
        the_list.append(the_value)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        myList = manager.list()
        pool = Pool(PROCESSES)
        for i in range(N):
            pool.apply_async(add_to_list, (myList, i))
        print('Closing...')
        pool.close()
        print('Joining...')
        pool.join()
        print(myList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that cpu_count() == 20 on my system.

The output is a list of N values in the inclusive range 0-249. This is exactly what I expect.

I then change the code so that:

```
pool = Pool()
```

In other words the pool size will default to 20

If I do so, I get this:

```
[Errno 61] Connection refused
```

...multiple times (it varies) from the exception handler in the add_to_list() function.

The join() then blocks indefinitely - i.e., the program never ends

I have determined that this unwanted behaviour arises when PROCESSES >= 18

If I Ctrl-C to stop the program, I see in the stack multiple references to:

```
return self._semlock.__enter__()
```

I deduce therefore that there's some kind of issue with Python's semaphore implementation that *may* be platform specific.

Is there a way to maximise the number of processes in the pool (cross platform) that would ensure that this situation doesn't arise?

Platform details:

```
macOS 13.5.1
3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W
32 GB 2666 MHz DDR4
Python 3.11.5
```

Comment: I see you've had this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74689719/connectionrefused-during-multiprocessing-of-a-queue

Comment: @Aaron You're right. However, the code is different (albeit contrived) and furthermore the alleged "fix" clearly hasn't been applied to the latest Python version.

Comment: weird idea, but maybe try editing "/py311/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py" change `Server.__init__` `self.listener` set `backlog` higher?

Comment: @Aaron I increased it from 16 to 32 and, with the code exactly as shown in my question, the error does **not** occur. The question now is "How big is big enough for this to be a viable solution?"

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the SocketClient function in multiprocessing/connection.py

Here's the original code:

```
def SocketClient(address):
    '''
    Return a connection object connected to the socket given by `address`
    '''
    family = address_type(address)
    with socket.socket( getattr(socket, family) ) as s:
        s.setblocking(True)
        s.connect(address)
        return Connection(s.detach())
```

Note that there is no exception handling. This implies that any failure to connect is unexpected. However, if the listening socket backlog is exceeded a "connection refused" exception is raised. This results, ultimately, in a deadlock.

The following modification solves my problem:

```
def SocketClient(address):
    '''
    Return a connection object connected to the socket given by `address`
    '''
    family = address_type(address)
    with socket.socket( getattr(socket, family) ) as s:
        s.setblocking(True)
        while True:
            try:
                s.connect(address)
                return Connection(s.detach())
            except ConnectionRefusedError:
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

Of course this should probably be more sophisticated but it works for me.

It's also worth noting (thanks to @Aaron for the suggestion) that the situation can be improved by increasing the backlog on the listener socket. The Server class (implemented in multiprocessing/managers.py) uses a hard-coded backlog value of 16. Increasing this value certainly helps to reduce the likelihood of this situation arising but is not, on its own, a complete solution.

Further note...

Given that the backlog is hard-coded at 16 then it appears from my experiments that the standard released code will work reliably **providing** the number of processes in the pool does not exceed the backlog value. Thus on systems where os.cpu_count() returns values <= 16 and Pool() is constructed with no specific limit, there would probably not be an issue

Comment: Polling can work in specific scenarios, but I wonder if this could have knock - on effects for other use cases (like getting stuck in the polling loop forever trying to connect to a server which will never respond). I found a [bug report from 2021](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88321) exactly describing the issue, and suggesting the backlog should be exposed as an optional argument to `BaseManager`. IMAO managers are useful, but a little bit cursed.